# Accept payments for subscription with all available payment methods

Tags: flutter, dart, payment-gateway, payment, flutter-web

How to accept payments from users for subscription by giving them a variety of payment options available including debit card, PayPal, bank transfer, other payment methods...I holding the subscription data in my database and just need a suitable payment plugin for transaction. I did a lot of research but couldn't get clear how to use and which one to use. I don't have any idea and can't figure out what to do. Please anyone give all details how it works and what should I do any suggestions?

Comment: This is a very broad question.  Stack Overflow is mostly intended for questions about specific coding (or similar) issues that you are encountering.  Flutter, itself, is not a payment processing platform - there would likely be a range of different Flutter packages that would integrate with different payment gateways (eg. Stripe is one example) - and yes, all of the different payment providers are going to have different fee structures.

Comment: Admittedly, there'll be some payment gateways that may not handle regular subscriptions, so to be honest you're probably better off first determining which payment provider will a) provide all of the functionality that you need, and b) has a fee structure that is acceptable to you - and then look at how their integration occurs and how easily you can incorporate that into your Flutter app.  It's very likely that you may need to hold some of the subscription information in your own server/database, then interact with the payment gateway to determine that regular payments occur successfully

Comment: Yes I will hold the subscription details in my database, I just need payment provider for trascation of payment...I have edited the question

Comment: Well, like I said, it's really up to you to choose which one will suit you best .... and that is a decision that almost really has nothing much to do with whether your app is a Flutter app or something else.  Yes, of course, you want to know that you can integrate with the platform - but depending on which country you're in, which currencies you want to be able to transact in, what sort of fees you want to pay, whether you have an existing merchant account with any bank, etc. ..... all of those are factors to consider before you even start planning the integration

Comment: Ok, what are the options I have to choose from? Am from India, and I want transaction taking place in all over world, I don't have an existing merchant account but I have normal account and at last I would like fees to be less but it doesn't matter much. So what are my options can you tell so that I can research on them an find out the best?

Comment: Stripe Payment Terminal EasyPie lets you accept payments and subscriptions from customers worldwide with a variety of payment methods | https://easypie.shop

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://razorpay.com/ flutter [package](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter) for this purpose.
Razorpay flutter [documentation](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/flutter-integration/)

Comment: Is it supported on web? I want it for flutter web..

Comment: it's a package that is supported in android and ios. but also it has API support so u can use this.

Comment: Any documentation how to use this?

Comment: Still can't get how to use on flutter web, have you ever used razorpay for web? Can you show an example code?